# Unable to logon using RDP after domain migration

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

We have issues after migrating a DC to a new DC.

When we attempt to RDP to some of our VMs using the DNS name, it fails. Using the IP address works.

This issue only occurs on some VMs.

It seems to be a DNS issue, but there is nothing wrong in the DNS.

Maybe some of you has a tip for me on what to change here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are all VMs actually using the new DC in their DNS settings?

Comment: Hi, yes the new DC is pushed to all VMs as DNS. The VMs are also pingable via DNS, only RDP does not work via DNS

Comment: What is the exact error you get when using RDP?

Comment: It basicly says "The login has failed" after typing in the password to auth. When i try it via IP with the same user to auth it works

Comment: have you verified, that the dns server is not set static? i mean even in the best networks, some clients have it set maybe fixed instead of using dhcp. and also verify, that the dns entries has been updated correctly, `ipconfig /flushdns` may do sometimes wonders.

Comment: This looks like a Kerberos issue... Kerberos is used when authenticating towards a hostname, but not towards an IP address. You should troubleshoot the authentication flow.

Comment: Do you also have issues accessing shares (such as C$) with \\hostname but not with \\ipaddress ?

Comment: Hi, on the VMs the DNS is set static on purpose, as they are application servers. Also i tried to flush the DNS but that does not change anything. I am sure the issue is on the DNS directly on the AD, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I will look into Kerberos. thanks!

Comment: Also accessing via SMB to C$ works

Comment: if you upgraded to a newer OS version, check your settings around NLA
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/5490.configure-network-level-authentication-for-remote-desktop-services-connections

Comment: Is there any clock skew?